# Exit on click x python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to exit by clicking x in python 
I made some programs but when the program finishes it closes automatically 
There is exitonclick in turtle but i don't know if there is something like that in python but not in turtle 
I 'm beginner in python

Comment: Are you executing it from windows command prompt? (double clicking)

Comment: Yes I execute it from command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of the two:

1) Execute the command with -i parameter

2) In your python script (at the end) add:

```
input("Press Enter to exit")
```